# Select parent div from inside the containing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a lot of old cached html file which uses document.write.
There are multiple element like this in every html file

```
<div class="time"><script>timeago('2008-06-07 17:40:53')</script></div>
```

`timeago` function writes time using `document.write` and the function is defined in a separate js file. So It is easy to alter the function to some thing else without changing some 200K documents.
But the issue is, how can I rewrite that timeago function to select the containing div and print the time. Is it possible to select the div from that script which is contained in that div may be using jQuery or native JavaScript?

Any advice please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this?

```html
<script>
function timeago(d) {
  document.currentScript.parentElement.innerText = 'output = ' + d;
}
</script>

<div class="time"><script>timeago('2008-06-07 17:40:53')</script></div>
```

Comment: If still supporting IE it needs a fallback also

Comment: Sure, something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/current-script-polyfill could be added if that was a need.

Comment: Not sure if many people still even supporting IE. Haven't looked at it's usage stats for a long time

Comment: @charlietfl anecdotally, there's still many many questions asked here that show that IE is being used (eg why doesn't `=>` work), so still worth mentioning when things aren't usable in IE.

Comment: charlietfl, Thanks for pointing out this IE exception. @Chase, Need to consider IE too, though ie users are very rare. I think I can just include the currentScript-polyfill js to the file right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly -- just make sure you add the polyfill support (before and) in addition to what is posted here and you should be good.